# Input box not working well on backspace/del

Tags: javascript, html, input

I have two input boxes that changes dynamically and depending on what number is put.. win chance ranges from 0.01% to 98% and the payout/multiplier ranges from 1.0102 to 9900

**http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yMbPGa**

So I have tried 5 DOM events for input below

**oninput** - It is the one i'm using now, but when I try to use backspace/del it sets it to lowest value and I can't delete it after that... another problem - I can't enter numbers like 1.1 or 0.1 in the inputs

**onkeyup** - Same problem as oninput but at least it will let me remove it but then it sets it also to lowest value.

Finally **onchange, onkeydown, onkeypress** doesn't work too well with my code.

```js
function wc(input) {
    if (input.value < 0.01) input.value = 0.01;
    if (input.value > 98) input.value = 98;
    y = 99 / input.value;
    y.toFixed(6);
    document.getElementById("payc").value = y;
}

function pc(input) {
    if (input.value < 1.0102) input.value = 1.0102;
    if (input.value > 9900) input.value = 9900;
    x = 99 / input.value;
    x.toFixed(6);
    document.getElementById("winc").value = x;
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
    <form action="/" method="post">
        <div class="top-row">
            <div class="field-wrap">
                <label class="active">
                    Win Chance
                </label>

                <input id="winc" value="49.5" type="text" oninput="wc(this);" autocomplete="off" />
            </div>

            <div class="field-wrap">
                <label class="active">
                    Payout
                </label>
                <input id="payc" value="2" type="text" oninput="pc(this);" autocomplete="off" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="button">Get Started</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

I don't know if the problem is my code,  I just what the backspace/del key to work as normal input but after the input lost focus just change to default value.

Comment: You are preventing the user from entering any value outside that range. I think that is what you need here?

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if you use onfocusout

```
<input id="winc" value="49.5" type="text" onfocusout="wc(this);" autocomplete="off"   />
```

Comment: Yes but I would like to have the dynamic changes instead and having the abiltiy to use del/backspace like onfocusout

Comment: In that case, you might have to rewrite the respective functions. There is clearly a conflict bw both  the functions.